# Way to count the number of parameters in a Scikit-Learn model

Tags: parameters, scikit-learn, count, neural-network

As far as I can tell there is no general attribute or method to return the total number of parameters (weights) in a Scikit-learn model.

I came up with this solution but not sure whether it works in all cases.

```
def n_params(model):
    """Return total number of parameters in a 
    Scikit-Learn model.

    This works for the following model types:
     - sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier
     - sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor
     - sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression
     - and maybe some others
    """
    return (sum([a.size for a in model.coefs_]) +  
            sum([a.size for a in model.intercepts_]))
```

Am I missing something more obvious/reliable?

One problem of course is whether this estimate should include 'hyper-parameters' but let's say I'm only interested in the weights.

For info, `model.get_params()` returns something like the following:

```
{'activation': 'relu',
 'alpha': 0.0001,
 'batch_size': 'auto',
 'beta_1': 0.9,
 'beta_2': 0.999,
 'early_stopping': False,
 'epsilon': 1e-08,
 'hidden_layer_sizes': (100,),
 'learning_rate': 'constant',
 'learning_rate_init': 0.001,
 'max_iter': 200,
 'momentum': 0.9,
 'n_iter_no_change': 10,
 'nesterovs_momentum': True,
 'power_t': 0.5,
 'random_state': None,
 'shuffle': True,
 'solver': 'adam',
 'tol': 0.0001,
 'validation_fraction': 0.1,
 'verbose': False,
 'warm_start': False}
```